React images not showing up after a day
I am facing an issue with my React application where the images are not showing up after a day of development. Here's how my setup looks:
I have a travelData.js file where I store my data, including image paths.
export default[
    {
        id: 1,
        img: 'images/cherry-blossoms-spring-chureito-pagoda-fuji-mountain-japan.jpg',
        location: 'Japan',
        mapLink: 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d13015.197565360711!2d138.71706365707905!3d35.36062456307495!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x6019629a42fdc899%3A0xa6a1fcc916f3a4df!2sMount%20Fuji!5e0!3m2!1sen!2smm!4v1715085848076!5m2!1sen!2smm',
        title: 'Mount Fuji',
        startDate: '12 Jan_2024',
        endDate: '24 Jan_2024',
        info: "Mount Fuji, Japan's iconic stratovolcano, stands at 3,776 meters tall, dominating the landscape with its symmetrical cone. Revered in Japanese culture, it's a UNESCO World Heritage Site, attracting hikers, artists, and pilgrims alike, offering breathtaking vistas and spiritual inspiration."
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        img: 'images/big-ben-westminster-bridge-sunset-london-uk.jpg',
        location: 'UK',
        mapLink: 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2483.680563854166!2d-0.1272003235304768!3d51.50072917181181!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487604c38c8cd1d9%3A0xb78f2474b9a45aa9!2sBig%20Ben!5e0!3m2!1sen!2smm!4v1715085764440!5m2!1sen!2smm',
        title: 'Big Ben',
        startDate: '21 Feb_2024',
        endDate: '28 Feb_2024',
        info: "Big Ben, an iconic symbol of London, stands tall at the north end of the Palace of Westminster. Its majestic clock tower, completed in 1859, chimes melodiously, keeping time for the bustling city below, while its intricate architecture captivates millions of visitors annually."
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        img: 'images/beautiful-shot-golden-gate-bridge-san-francisco-foggy-day.jpg',
        location: 'USA',
        mapLink: 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2483.680563854166!2d-0.1272003235304768!3d51.50072917181181!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487604c38c8cd1d9%3A0xb78f2474b9a45aa9!2sBig%20Ben!5e0!3m2!1sen!2smm!4v1715085764440!5m2!1sen!2smm',
        title: 'Golden Gate',
        startDate: '1 Mar_2024',
        endDate: '20 Mar_2024',
        info: "The Golden Gate Bridge, an iconic suspension bridge in San Francisco, spans the Golden Gate Strait, connecting the city with Marin County. Its distinctive red-orange hue, breathtaking vistas, and engineering marvel make it a globally renowned landmark symbolizing innovation and beauty."
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        img: 'images/pagoda-bagan.jpg',
        location: 'Myanmar',
        mapLink: 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2483.680563854166!2d-0.1272003235304768!3d51.50072917181181!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487604c38c8cd1d9%3A0xb78f2474b9a45aa9!2sBig%20Ben!5e0!3m2!1sen!2smm!4v1715085764440!5m2!1sen!2smm',
        title: 'Bagan Pagoda',
        startDate: '24 Mar_2024',
        endDate: '31 Mar_2024',
        info: "Bagan Pagoda, an ancient city in Myanmar, boasts over 2,000 well-preserved Buddhist temples and stupas dating back to the 9th century. Its vast plains, adorned with architectural marvels, offer a surreal glimpse into the region's rich cultural and spiritual heritage."
    }
]

I have a Card component where I display the data, including the images.
import React from 'react'

const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='container mx-auto flex flex-col space-y-2 items-center space-x-3 p-3 max-w-7xl md:space-y-0 md:flex-row'>
                <div className='w-full h-64 md:max-w-56 select-none hover:blur-sm transition-all duration-300'>
                    <img className='w-full h-full object-cover rounded-lg' src={props.item.img} alt="Image" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i class="ri-map-pin-line text-red-500"></i>
                    <span className='text-slate-500'>{props.item.location}</span>
                    <span className='ml-1 text-slate-400'><a className='underline text-xs' href={props.item.mapLink}>View on Google Maps</a></span>
                    <h1 className='text-3xl font-semibold mb-7'>{props.item.title}</h1>
                    <p className='space-x-1 font-semibold text-sm mb-2'><span>{props.item.startDate}</span><span>-</span><span>{props.item.endDate}</span></p>
                    <p className='text-sm leading-6'>{props.item.info}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card

I use map to render multiple Card components based on the data from travelData.js.
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Card from "./components/Card";
import travelData from "./travelData";
import Main from "./components/Main";
import Button from "./components/Button";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

function App() {

  const card = travelData.map(item => {
    return(
      <Card 
        key = {item.id}
        item = {item}
      />
    )
  })

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Main />
      <section className="p-3 pb-0 grid grid-cols-1 xl:grid-cols-2"> 
        {card}
      </section>
      <section className="flex justify-center p-8">
          <Button />
      </section>
      <Footer />
    </>
  ); 
}

export default App;

My images are stored in the public/images folder.
Initially, everything works fine, and the images are displayed properly. However, after a day, when I reopen my laptop and run the React application again, the images are not showing up anymore.
I've ensured that:
The image paths in travelData.js are correct.
The images are present in the public/images folder.
I haven't made any changes to the code or folder structure since it was working.
Despite these efforts, the images are still not showing up.
Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening and how to fix it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
